# What is a good implementation of Facebook API on a mobile device?

Tags: ios, xamarin

I'm making an app with xamarin.iOS using Facebook API to login but I would like to know if my app should make the connection to the Facebook api or should I make a call to my asp net mvc webapi and let my backend make the connection to the Facebook API.

so here are the 2 concept :

mobile communicate directly with facebook api and after send the data to my asp webapi

or mobile request asp webapi then webapi make a request to facebook api

wich concept should I take ?

Comment: I'd suggest you go with 1st approach and use Facebook SDK for iOS to make sure it uses native screens/experience when possible. Then pass the token to the backend and then use it how you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From mobile user prospective, it is better to use Facebook SDK for iOS in the mobile app so that the experience stays native all the way.
Remember, iOS supports Facebook even without Facebook app installed.

Facebook SDK for iOS takes care of all this.

After you login, you can send your token to the Web API and then use it.

Here are some articles and videos that will help you getting started:

[Facebook iOS SDK for Xamarin - Getting started](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/facebookios)

Video: [Login with Facebook in Xamarin Forms](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/MVP-Windows-Dev/Login-with-Facebook-in-Xamarin-Forms)